# How can I show the suggestion bar over the keyboard

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

[image]I need to show the suggestion bar over the keyboard, while I am typing there must be some word suggestions & on tap of suggested words those must be updated in TextInput field.

In React-Native for iOS & android both.
I have scene the InputAccessoryView but it is not working.

I have also used  as well, but not showing any bar on keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall iOS keyboard suggestions are turned on by default.

For android I recommend having a look on the attributes `autoCompleteType`
http://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#autocompletetype

Comment: But I am not seeing any suggestion bar over the keyboard. Please check the screen shot.

Comment: This is odd... There isn't much talking about this settings being related to react native. Did you check on that iOS' Settings app if the keyboard's suggestions are on? On my iPhone it's currently turned on, and every time I open the keyboard within my apps the suggestions are showing up.